# Can I do crunch and twist exercise on bed?

Tags: exercise

Exercises like crunch and twist in which we have to lean on floor but can we do this on a bed? Our bed mattress is mostly hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but the bed will absorb a lot of your movement which makes it easier to do and can make it hard to achieve good form.

You can try doing a pushup on a bed as an example: you can sort of do it, but without the full resistance of the floor your back is at a weird angle and your hands sink into the mattress.

It's the same reason that you should squat and deadlift (and most other barbell lifts) with flat non-squishy shoes (converse, etc) on hard flooring like concrete. It's the same reason gloves are generally frowned upon: it's squishy stuff between you and something hard (the bar).